# Reading a text file to form a maze in java

Tags: java, bufferedreader

I'm pretty new to java and have the following text file I want to turn into a maze:

```
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
************************S************************
*******************      *F    ******************
****************   * * *******    ***************
**************    *         * ***   *************
*************  *                 **   ***********
************  *    **    *         **  **********
**********   *      *   ***      **     *********
**********          **         **     *   *******
***************       **     **     *****  ******
*****************       ** **      ******* ******
******************        *  *   *********  *****
******* ************         * ************ *****
******      ********** *    * **********     ****
******  **    ********  *  * ********        ****
*****  ***      *******  *   ******    * ***  ***
*****  ** *       ****** *  ******     * ***  ***
****   ** *     ******** *  ********   *  **  ***
****   ** *    ** *******  ******* ** * * **   **
****  ** * *** **  ******  ******  **  *   *   **
****  **  * *  **********  ********** *** ***  **
****  *** **** ********* *  ********* **  ***  **
**** ****  ***  *******      *******  ** ****  **
**** ***** ***   ******       *****  *   ***** **
****  ****  * *    **               *** *****  **
****  ** **   ** *     *     *     * * ***** * **
****  *******     * * ********* * *   ** ****  **
**** ***** *****   * * * *** ***  ****** ***   **
****  ** **   *******   *** *  ******* **** * ***
*****  ***** * * ********* ***** **  * ****** ***
*****  **  *** *  *  **********   *  * * **   ***
****** ** * ** *  *  *   **   *   *  *** **  ****
******  ***  ***  *  *        ** ** *** ***  ****
******   ** *  ***** *    *    * ****   **  *****
*******   *** * ** ****   *   **** ** ***  ******
********   **** *  * **********   * ***   *******
*********   ****  *     *       * * *** *********
**********    *****  *        * ******  *********
*********** *    ***** ** ** ********** *********
************  **   **************  ** ***********
**************** *               **  ************
**************** *******      **** **************
******************  ****** ****  ****************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
*************************************************
```

The problem is that I keep getting a "file error" message (from line 202) every time I try to upload the file. Here's my main program:

```
/*
 * MazeRunner.java
 *
 */
package mazerunner;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class MazeRunner extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public static final int wall = 0;
    public static final int open = 1;
    public static final int visited = 2;
    public static final int onpath = 3;
    public static final int start = 4;
    public static final int end = 5;
    public static final int pending = 6;
    public static final int mazeSize = 50;
    public static Color[] colors = {Color.BLACK, Color.WHITE, Color.MAGENTA, Color.ORANGE,
        Color.CYAN, Color.RED, Color.LIGHT_GRAY};
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
    public int maze[][] = new int[mazeSize][mazeSize];
    public Timer clock = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            tick();
            mazePanel.repaint();
        }
    });

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new MazeRunner().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class MyPanel extends JPanel {

        @Override
        public void paint(Graphics g) {
            super.paint(g);
            for (int i = 0; i < mazeSize; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < mazeSize; j++) {
                    g.setColor(colors[maze[i][j]]);
                    g.fillRect(i, j, 12, 12);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public MazeRunner() {
        initComponents();
        clock.start();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        mazePanel = new MyPanel();
        loadMaze = new javax.swing.JButton();
        collectionSelection = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
        title = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        mazePanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 204));
        mazePanel.setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(600, 600));

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout mazePanelLayout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(mazePanel);
        mazePanel.setLayout(mazePanelLayout);
        mazePanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            mazePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        mazePanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            mazePanelLayout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(0, 600, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        loadMaze.setText("Load File");
        loadMaze.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                loadMazeActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        collectionSelection.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Stack", "Queue" }));

        title.setText("No File Loaded");

        org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout layout = new org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addContainerGap()
                        .add(mazePanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(54, 54, 54)
                        .add(title, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 351, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .add(28, 28, 28)
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(loadMaze, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .add(46, 46, 46))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(collectionSelection, 0, 111, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addContainerGap())))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
            .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .add(layout.createParallelGroup(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.LEADING)
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(loadMaze)
                        .add(81, 81, 81)
                        .add(collectionSelection, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                    .add(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .add(title, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 25, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(org.jdesktop.layout.LayoutStyle.UNRELATED)
                        .add(mazePanel, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                .addContainerGap(org.jdesktop.layout.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void loadMazeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

        int retval = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
        if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                String s;
                while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < mazeSize; i++) {
                        for (int j = 0; j < mazeSize; j++) {


                            if (s.charAt(j) == '*') {
                                maze[i][j] = wall;
                            }
                            if (s.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                                maze[i][j] = open;
                            }
                            if (s.charAt(j) == 'F') {
                                maze[i][j] = end;
                            }
                            if (s.charAt(j) == 'S') {
                                maze[i][j] = start;
                            } else {
                                maze[i][j] = wall;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                title.setText("File Error");
            }
        }

    }                                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JComboBox collectionSelection;
    private javax.swing.JButton loadMaze;
    private javax.swing.JPanel mazePanel;
    private javax.swing.JLabel title;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

I think the problem lies in this code segment, but no matter how I fool with it, I can't get it to work:

```
private void loadMazeActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

            int retval = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(this);
            if (retval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
                File file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                    String s;
                    while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < mazeSize; i++) {
                            for (int j = 0; j < mazeSize; j++) {


                                if (s.charAt(j) == '*') {
                                    maze[i][j] = wall;
                                }
                                if (s.charAt(j) == ' ') {
                                    maze[i][j] = open;
                                }
                                if (s.charAt(j) == 'F') {
                                    maze[i][j] = end;
                                }
                                if (s.charAt(j) == 'S') {
                                    maze[i][j] = start;
                                } else {
                                    maze[i][j] = wall;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    title.setText("File Error");
                }
            }

        }
```

Here's the generated stacktrace:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 49
    at java.lang.String.charAt(String.java:686)
    at mazerunner.MazeRunner.loadMazeActionPerformed(MazeRunner.java:172)
    at mazerunner.MazeRunner.access$100(MazeRunner.java:19)
    at mazerunner.MazeRunner$3.actionPerformed(MazeRunner.java:111)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2028)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2351)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6382)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6147)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2083)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4744)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2141)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4619)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4280)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4210)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2127)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4572)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:704)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:677)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:675)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction it would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please post the full exception stacktrace text and indicate which line in your code above throws the exception.

Comment: The code you've posted is a maze my friend...

Comment: There's no exception text, just a title that pops up on my JFrame as per line 202 of the program ((catch (Exception e)).

Comment: @FionaCat86 - you need to CHANGE you program so that it does generate a stacktrace.  Add `e.printStackTrace()` to the exception handler.

Comment: Ok, I just did that and added it to main post. Thanks!

Comment: The problem is on line 172 of MazeRunner.java. You are trying to access a character in a String at an invalid index. What is this line?

Comment: if (s.charAt(j) == '*') maze[i][j] = wall;

Comment: Are you sure you have **50** characters in **every** line of your file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your maze size is not actually 50. First off because you are starting to count at 0 it needs to be one less than it actually is. Secondly there are only 49 characters in each line of the file that you provided. Just change mazesize to 48 and it should work. You may want to work on making your code a bit easier to read though.

Comment: Thank you, definitely something I should have caught before posting this.

Comment: I suggest using the length of the String rather than an unrelated variable. This will ensure that you don't go past the end of the String.

Answer (score 2):

The problem occurs on this line:

```
if (s.charAt(j) == '*')
```

The error tells you that the index (`j`) is larger than the number of characters in the `String` (`s`). So look at how you set the values of `j`:

```
for (int j = 0; j < mazeSize; j++)
```

We can deduce `mazeSize` is bigger than the length of `s`. You should figure out a different ending condition for your loop.

*p.s.* I suggest that you learn how to debug your own code so you can find these problems on your own. There are other issues with your code that I won't go into here. You will make some progress solving them by adding `System.out.println()` statements throughout your code or using a debugger from an IDE.

Answer (score 0):

As said before the problem comes from the fact that every line of your file doesn't contain 50 buts 49 (or 48) characters. 
IMO there is no need to do this double `for-statement` because you're already reading a String for every line of your file that represents the maze with this line of code :

```
String s;
while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) {
```

So you just have to do one for-statement here in the while and don't have to choose arbitrarily the size of your String, but instead :

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) {
    if(s.charAt(i) == '*') {
        // etc...
```

So finally your statement will be :

```
String s;

while ((s = reader.readLine()) != null) 
{
    for(int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++) 
    {
        if(s.charAt(i) == '*') { maze[i][j] = wall; }
        if(s.charAt(j) == ' ') { maze[i][j] = open; }
        if(s.charAt(j) == 'F') { maze[i][j] = end; }
        if(s.charAt(j) == 'S') { maze[i][j] = start; } 
        else { maze[i][j] = wall; }
    }
}
```